# Парсинг на Python. Обработка shadow root (Closed). Как нажать на кнопку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Имеется сайт:
[каталог компаний](https://www.firmy.cz/Auto-moto/Auto-moto-prodejci/Autobazary)

При заходе на сайт, выдает окно, где требуется нажать на кнопку "Согласен". Кнопка находится в блоке shadow-root (**closed**). Влоб получить данные из него нельзя. Нагуглил, что есть способ при помощи TAB спуститься от первого тега вне блока и там найти нужный элемент. Но все равно выдает ошибки и не находит нужный элемент. Кто решал такие вопросы, помогите.
Вот код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"D:\Python_lern\pythonProject\files     \chromedriver.exe")

url = "https://www.firmy.cz/Auto-moto/Auto-moto-prodejci/Autobazary"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
over_root = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[20]')))
action = ActionChains(driver)
under_root = action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[20]//div[2]  /div/div[2]/button[2]')))
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

driver.quit()
```

Вот ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Python_lern\pythonProject\files\lern.py", line 21, in 
> element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[20]//div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT314.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT314.png)/button[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT314.png)')))
> File "D:\Python_lern\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
> Stacktrace:
> Backtrace:
> Ordinal0 [0x00B96463+2188387]
> Ordinal0 [0x00B2E461+1762401]

Вот кнопка в коде на сайте:

[image: Кнопка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересная задача..

Банально, однако обойти можно с помощью библиотеки pyautogui.

```
url = "https://www.firmy.cz/Auto-moto/Auto-moto-prodejci/Autobazary"
driver.get(url)
sleeping_(10) #Не обращай внимание, тут просто функция с time.sleep(10) ждал пока откроется модальное окно
pyautogui.click(x=425, y=531)
pyautogui.press('TAB')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('TAB')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('TAB')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('TAB')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('TAB')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('TAB')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('ENTER')
```

Или сразу найти координаты - x, y кнопки и кликнуть всего 1 раз.